# How to set a button clickable when clicking another button?

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to programming and I've been trying to build a Skilltree for my tablerpg, I wanted to have the Skill buttons unclickable until you click the previous Skill button, so far I've got this

```
    Button btn_for = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Fortificacao);
    Button btn_ten = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Ten);
    //btn_for.setOnClickListener(btn_ten.setClickable(true));
```

the commented line is not working and I have no idea why if someone can give me some advice I'd be grateful <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initially set the button disabled either in xml or through code.

```
android:enabled="false"
```

Then on click of the button you can make it enabled

```
Button btn_for = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Fortificacao);
    Button btn_ten = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Ten);
        btn_for.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            btn_ten .setEnabled(true);

        }
 });
```